# Data migrations for older version of friendly id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I'm migrating a very old app from friendly_id 3.2 to 5.1.

I have a user model which currently has a `cached_slug` field. I created a new field called just `slug`. Initially, I thought I could just copy the data over from cached_slug to slug, but I noticed that there's also a whole other table called slugs which looks like this:

```
  create_table "slugs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",           limit: 255
    t.integer  "sluggable_id"
    t.integer  "sequence",                   default: 1, null: false
    t.string   "sluggable_type", limit: 40
    t.string   "scope",          limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end
```

Following the directions in the FriendlyID README for the Rails Quickstart, I ran `rails generate friendly_id` which created this table:

```
create_table "friendly_id_slugs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "slug",                      null: false
    t.integer  "sluggable_id",              null: false
    t.string   "sluggable_type", limit: 50
    t.string   "scope"
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end
```

So now I'm all confused about what I need to do to complete migration. I tried creating a new user with the console and the `friendly_id_slugs` table is still empty, so I'm not sure when or what it's used for.

I have two questions:
1) What is this other table used for
2) What do I need to do to migrate my old slugs to the new table/field so it will continue to work moving forward?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind losing the [FriendlyId's History](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId/History) records (i.e: the old slugs),

1. drop the old `slug` table
2. in the rails console, run  `<ModelName>.find_each(&:save)` for all friendly_id models.

Step 2 should regenerate new slugs.

Warning: Test before doing this on production servers!

Update: You can also perform step 2 in a migration file

```
class RegenerateSlugs < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        # <ModelName>.find_each(&:save)
        User.find_each(&:save)
        Article.find_each(&:save)
    end
end
```

Comment: I'd like to keep old slugs for SEO reasons. It read through some of the source this weekend, and it looks like I don't need all extra tables unless I want to use :history. So I could just copy from the old cached_slugs into the new .slug field, I may use some historical context, but that's a very small % of my use cases, so should be good enough. Thanks!